# Why am I not able to catch Pokémon abroad?

Tags: pokemon-go

I originally live in India but currently I'm visiting Bangkok and though I did find some new Pokémons every time I get them in the Pokeball, they get out in the first try and run away. Neither am I able to get stuff from the poke stops. Will someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: Has this started just recently, or is it an ongoing problem?

Comment: Have you tried shutting it off and turning it on again? This is actually a serious question, since the game can sometimes soft-ban you if you last played the game a long distance from where you are now.

Answer (score 6):

The issue you have encountered is called as Soft ban. You will **not** be able to catch pokemon neither be able to get items from pokestops. It happens if you **travel long distance in short amount of time** , it is included to prevent Pokemon sniping and GPS spoofing. Soft- Ban usually last for 1-3 days or may last up to 1 week depending on distance. So wait for some days you will be fine and don't use any hacks (GPS spoofs) to prevent it.

Comment: It can also be temporary. I've seen a softban, but restarting the game removes it.

Comment: Hasn't there been a thing with spinning a PokeStop while being softbanned for a certain amount and then the softban will be removed? Not sure though

Comment: @GrizZ Yep I read it when I was soft banned though its just fake. Nothing else